# Boostrap modal not loading when wired using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I have the following link and I'm trying to load a bootstrap modal when its clicked but the javascript function doesnt seem to be firing. Instead of the view loading inside a modal, its loading as a new page?

```
<a href="/Reports/ReportSummary" class="icon-before js-report-summary" data-icon="\uf080"> </a>

 @*this is the modal definition*@
 <div class="modal hide fade in" id="report-summary">
     <div id="report-summary-container"></div>
 </div>


<script >
 $('a.js-report-summary').click(function (e) {
   var url = $(this).attr('href'); // the url to the controller
   e.preventDefault();      
   $.get(url, function (data) {
      $('#report-summary-container').html(data);
      $('#report-summary').modal('show');
  });
});
</script>


 public ActionResult ReportSummary()
 {
     // some actions


     return PartialView("ReportSummary", viewmodel)

 }

 // Report summary view which contains modal

 <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">@ViewBag.FormName - Analysis</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">

            ...
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">
                Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

There are no errors showing in the console either so why isn't the jquery function firing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your click function, add parameter `e` this will stand for `event`
then in the function itself add `e.preventDefault()` This will stop the refreshing effect.

Comment: Adding the above I get the fade effect but the modal isnt displaying? Console shows status 200 for the jquery function so it seems like its retrieved it but why is it not displaying?

Comment: Also, that href is never gonna work. You'll have to bind a route to the controller action

Comment: See updated code. The controller actions does work but the modal isnt showing. Its just generating the fade effect over the existing page.

Answer (score 0):

on your controller method try

```
 public ViewResult ReportSummary()
 {
     // some actions

     if(Request.IsAjaxRequest())
         return PartialView("ReportSummary", viewmodel);
     else
         return View("ReportSummary", viewmodel);

 }
```

on your view

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {//give your model wrapper an id
  //do some ajax and get html
$.ajax({
    url:'',
    success:function(data){
        $('#report-summary-container').html(data);
    }
});

})
```

on your anchor tag, add `data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal"`

if you dont want to use bootstrap events trigger your modal with

```
$('#myModal').modal('show')
```

Comment: how do i get the href from the anchor?

Comment: if you mean the href url of the anchor, you can use $('.js-report-summary').attr('href');

Comment: I think I've fixed it. My original code was correct. I needed to remove the hide class from the following definition `<div class="modal hide fade in" id="report-summary">`. Your method also works but I have multiple anchors with different hrefs to toggle the modal so using `$(.js-report-summary'.attr('href')` wont work. I would somehow need to get the correct href of the clicked anchor.